# Proper way of ReasonML record pattern-matching

Tags: pattern-matching, reason

I have a record type that goes,

```
type person = {
 name: string,
 gender: string,
 age: int
}
```

and have lots of records that fit with the type. What I want to do is to extract only [name, age] from the person and make a new record. To do so, I initially thought of using a pattern-matching technique that goes like,

```
switch(input) {
  |({name, _, gender} => //make a new record by extracting only name and age
  |_ => ();
}
```

Does this approach make sense? If so, how should I go about it?
If not, what would be the proper way of deleting a key from a record(records are immutable, so this doesn't really make sense), or extracting another record from an existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need a switch to pattern-match.

Basically, just using
`let {name, gender, age: _} = input` is enough to extract the two attributes you want.

Your could make a helper function like this:

```ml
type person = {
  name: string,
  gender: string,
  age: int,
};

type nameAndGender = {
  name: string,
  gender: string,
};

let personToNameAndGender = (person) => {
  let {name, gender, age: _} = person;
  {name, gender};
};
```

Keep in mind that you need to define both record types beforehand.

NOTE: You can also omit the age if you just match on the partial record

```ml
let {name, gender}: person = person;
```

but then you need to annotate it since the type system cannot figure out automatically which of the two records it is.

Here is a [working example](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&reason=C4TwDgpgBJBODOB7AdlAvFA3gKClZAhgLYQBcU8wsAlsgOYA0uUdEyAJhLOZTfU3gKtytYEwC+AbmzZQkfMQgBBDgHE2nWOizNCJHlVqNmrDlwN9jUmQBsIwGFyTIAKogByile3VnYS7ThndAA+HTw7B0w9CAYWDS44oTIoAH1xQKcUaTxoxTjTTWtrbEjHBBQ3TxJvX00AIUyK1DQwnAj7LBiChNhxciCUJuccrvz4v2LpUs7aMABXBww8-SgAIgApRAALVAARRAg1nr9yNaICO2OoZPIAZgAGEsHXDy81XqUACjnFgEoALQhDbwAB0NkQdGkLyq7x8vXqP2QC2AgOBYIhUOwQA).